# How to handle lifetimes when working with generators that take references?

Tags: rust, iterator, generator, lifetime

I'm currently working on implementing an iterator that generates a lot of objects and returns them. Since this code has a lot of checks I wanted to use a generator from the [genawaiter crate](https://docs.rs/genawaiter/latest/genawaiter/index.html), so as to not having to implement a lot of states. However, as the function that should construct the generator only gets references of its inputs I always get problems with the lifetimes of these references.

I tried annotating the lifetimes for the sub-functions, like so:

```rs
use genawaiter::{rc::gen, yield_};

pub struct TermGenerator {
    pub prefix: Term,
    pub suffix: Term,
}

impl TermGenerator {
    pub fn generate(&self, text: &Term) -> MyIter {
        let iter = self.get_prefix_terms(text).chain(self.get_suffix_terms(text));
        MyIter { iter: Box::new(iter)}
    }

    fn get_prefix_terms<'a>(&'a self, text: &'a Term) -> impl Iterator<Item = Term> + 'a {
        gen!({
            yield_!(Term::from(format!("{}-", self.prefix)));
            yield_!(Term::from(format!("{}-{}", self.prefix, text)));
        }).into_iter()
    }

    fn get_suffix_terms<'a>(&'a self, text: &'a Term) -> impl Iterator<Item = Term> + 'a {
        gen!({
            yield_!(Term::from(format!("{}-", self.suffix)));
            yield_!(Term::from(format!("{}-{}", self.suffix, text)));
        }).into_iter()
    }

    ...
}

struct MyIter {
    iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Term>>,
    ...
}
```

(code is simplified, real example has a lot more checks)

But now I have a problem in the `generate` function, because the lifetimes of `text` and `self` are not guaranteed to outlive the iterator.

Is there some way to make the iterator independent of these references?

**Update #1**
Another piece of code (not written by me) is using `MyIter` like this:

```rs
impl Dataset {
    fn store_encoded_terms(&self, term: &Term) -> impl Iterator<Item = Term> + 'static {
        self.term_generator.generate(term)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid capturing the parameters alltogether by just `format!`ing outside of the `gen!` invocations:

```rust
    fn get_prefix_terms(&self, text: &Term) -> impl Iterator<Item = Term> {
        let prefix = format!("{}-", self.prefix);
        let prefix2 = format!("{}-{}", self.prefix, text);
        gen!({
            yield_!(Term::from(prefix));
            yield_!(Term::from(prefix2));
        }).into_iter()
    }
```

To get a `impl Iterator + 'static` you can't mention any non-static references within `gen!` as it has to capture those.

If it's fine for your final iterator to not be bound by `'static` you can instead annotate the lifetime requirement everywhere:

```rust
impl TermGenerator {
    pub fn generate<'a>(&'a self, text: &'a Term) -> MyIter<'a> {
```

```rust
struct MyIter<'a> {
    iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Term> + 'a>,
}
```

Comment: I now have a similar problem at a different place. I've added an edit to my original post to show how `MyIter` is used and in this case I cannot do the same thing. Is there maybe some other way to avoid having to propagate the lifetime all the way through?